# Local module import not working in python3, but working for python2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-import

I have a dir structure like this

```
.
./main.py
->sub_dir
    ./client.py
    ./config.py
```

**main.py**

```
from sub_dir.client import Client
```

**client.py**

```
    from config import *
```

**config.py**

```
    url="138.12.12.32"
```

$ python2 main.py -> works Normally

$ python3 main.py

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nipun.pruthi/Flipkart/tasks/NonPromisableSolve/lot_expiry/alert_NonExpiry.py", line 9, in <module>
    from qaas.qaas_client import QaasClient
  File "/Users/nipun.pruthi/Flipkart/tasks/NonPromisableSolve/lot_expiry/qaas/qaas_client.py", line 5, in <module>
    from config import qaasEndpoint
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'
```

Comment: Try a relative import: `from .config import *` (note the dot)

Comment: Python 3 adds `relative import` for modules.